# spark regression example invalid syntax error

Tags: lambda, apache-spark, regression, pyspark

I am trying examples from [the page][1]. Why do I get invalid syntax error?

```
>>> MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda (v,p): (v - p)**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda (v,p): (v - p)**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Version info

```
>>> print(sys.version)
3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 15:01:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

I tried suggestions given in comments, but no luck

```
>>> MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda v, p: (v - p)**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
[Stage 179:>                                                        (0 + 2) / 2]16/03/14 20:06:22 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 179.0 (TID 346)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: which Python version are you running?

Comment: it is 3. But how can i confirm that?

Comment: Which Spark version are you using? I noticed the Spark docs link you provided referred to a very old version.
Here's the latest link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression

If using Python 3, you may need to remove the parenthesis and just reference `lambda v, p:` I'd recommend sticking to python 2.7 for now to reduce these types of issues.

Comment: spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6

Comment: When you enter `pyspark` one of the last lines should say `Using Python version` and number, if it's not `2.X` then you better change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark should tell you which Python version its using:

```
$ ./pyspark
...
Using Python version 2.7.10 (default, Dec 25 2015 13:37:32)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
```

You can check your python version in the console with `python --version` command. If you are using Python version 3 then in that version the syntax you're using is not correct and should be:

```
valuesAndPreds.map(lambda kv: (kv[0] - kv[1])**2)
```

Then again I don't know how well `PySpark` will work with Python3.

If you want to run with Python 2 you can do it by exporting this env variable `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2`. You can do it also while starting `pyspark` like this `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2 ./bin/pyspark`